# Always a prime between $x$ and $x+cf(x)$

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

What is the asymptotically slowest growing function $f(x)$, such that there exists constants $a$ and $b$, such that for all $x>a$, there is always a prime between $x$ and $x+bf(x)$?

$f(x)=x$ works, does $\sqrt{x}$ work, $\log(x)$, or $\log\log(x)$?

Comment: I'm not sure this is known.

Comment: The Oppermann's conjecture conjectures that there is a prime between $x - \sqrt{x}$, $x$ and $x + \sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are looking at is an upper bound for [prime gaps.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap)  Bertrands postulate states that there is always a prime between $x$ and $2x$, but this has been improved significantly.  The most recent result due to Baker Harman and Pintz states that $$\pi\left(x+x^{0.525}\right)
-\pi(x)\gg \frac{x^{0.525}}{\log x}.$$ This means that for sufficiently large $x$, there is always a prime between $x$ and $x+x^{0.525}$.  This implies for example that there is always a prime between consecutive cubes, that is there is always a prime in the interval $(x^3,(x+1)^3)$.

As for the expected result, the Wikipedia article covers this as well, see [Conjectures about prime gaps.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Conjectures_about_gaps_between_primes)  In particular, the Riemann Hypothesis tells us that for any $\epsilon$, we will have a prime in the interval $(x,x+x^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon})$ for sufficiently large $x$.  Cramer made the much stronger conjecture that there is always be a prime between $x$ and $x+\log^2x$ for sufficiently large $x$.

Comment: Looking at the conjectures for prime gaps $g_n$, from  [Riemann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Large_prime_gap_conjecture) $g(p_n)=O(\sqrt{p_n} \log p_n)$, to [Cramer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture) $g(p_n)=O((\log p_n)^2),\ $ reminds me a little of the complexity evolution from FastFourierTransform to QuantumFourierTranform...

Comment: @draks: I am unfamiliar with this, but curious, would you mind elaborating?

Comment: The sequence of $n$ complex numbers $x_0, ..., x_{n−1}$ can be [fast fourier transformed]() into another sequence of $n$ complex numbers in $O_{FFT}(n2^n)$ operations. This is more efficient than just matrix-vector multiplying ${\bf F}\vec x$, with ${\bf F}$ the [FourierMatrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierMatrix.html). It was found that $\bf F$ can be implemented on quantum computer in only $O_{QFT}(n^2)$ steps, which was used by Peter Shor to show that there exist

Comment: [Polynomial-Time Algorithms for Prime Factorization and Discrete Logarithms on a Quantum Computer](http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/quant-ph/9508027). Now replace $n$ by $\log p_n$ and we are back where we started (beside some scalar factors).

Comment: To all that are interested in Quantum Information: The [Quantum Information and Foundations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36039/quantum-information-and-foundations?referrer=G-oXDJgd8JaWXYyF_kRbzQ2) proposal is currently in commitment phase.

Comment: @draks: Thanks for the comment!