# Is an upper bound known for the least exponent $k$ such that $(\pi(n^k)-\pi(n))_{n=1}^\infty$ is strictly increasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Is an upper bound known for the least exponent $k$ such that $(\pi(n^k)-\pi(n))_{n=1}^\infty$ is strictly increasing?

It appears that the sequence is strictly increasing when $k\geq2$, but

$$(\pi(n^2)-\pi(n))-(\pi((n-1)^2)-\pi(n-1))\\=(\pi(n^2)-\pi((n-1)^2))-(\pi(n)-\pi(n-1))$$

implies this is stronger than Legendre's conjecture, as we must have at least $2$ primes between $(n-1)^2$ and $n^2$ if $n$ is prime, and at least $1$ prime if $n$ is composite. In general, it seems that asking if it is true for a given $k$ is nearly as strong as asking if there are at least $2$ primes between $(n-1)^k$ and $n^k$. I think the $k=3$ variant of Legendre's conjecture is also known only under RH.

Is the sequence known to be strictly increasing for any $k>2$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppermann%27s_conjecture

Comment: Do you have a cite for "I think the k=3 variant...?"

Comment: @daniel [Here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.4883.pdf) is one of several mentions I've found of a prime between $(n-1)^3$ and $n^3 being easy to prove under RH, but I've found no mention of an independent proof.

Comment: @JaycobColeman To be more precise, it's definitely true for all sufficiently large enough $n$ without RH (see Baker-Harman-Pintz), so I suspect the conditional part is just to get the lower bound down far enough to verify the rest computationally.  Ah, this is confirmed in your link.

Comment: Also, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142535/always-a-prime-between-x-and-xcfx